# HHVM is breaking display in Manage Currency Rates

Tags: nginx, server-setup, hhvm

Our Magento store is running on an NGINX server & HHVM.

I've noticed that when you go to **System > Manage Currency Rates** the currency fields are displayed in the wrong order, they've all been shifted to the right.

Our base currency is Euro but the field with the euro rate is displayed beneath the GBP column.

They are:
[image]

As opposed to:
[image]

When I inspect the field with the *1.000* curency rate it has `name="rate[EUR][EUR]"` for which confirms the fields are in the wrong position.

There is nothing showing up in my HHVM or NGINX error logs.

Also I have `hhvm.enable_zend_sorting = 1` & `hhvm.enable_obj_destruct_call = 1` set in my /etc/hhvm/php.ini and /etc/hhvm/server.ini files.

Has anyone else using HHVM and Magento noticed this or have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reported the [issue to HHVM on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5862) and interestingly while this error is occurring on recent versions of HHVM it is not on there latest nightly and should be fixed in version 3.9 of HHVM which is to be released sometime this month.

**UPDATE**

Confirmed that this solution worked when I I upgraded to version 3.9 of HHVM.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended by Daniel Sloof here:

http://youtu.be/BfTx2hWgylM

You should enable the support for Zend PHP alike sort stability using:

```
hhvm.enable_zend_sorting = 1
```

inside:

`/etc/hhvm/php.ini`

or:

`/etc/hhvm/server.ini`

More info on this and other switches here:

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/INI-Settings

Comment: thanks for the links.  I already have hhvm.enable_zend_sorting = 1 in my ini files but am still getting this issue.  Do you experience this issue with HHVm & Magento?

Comment: FYI this issue will be fixed in next release of HHVM, see my answer.